# autoopen pure css modal on pageload without javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I need a pure CSS modal in order to show a disclaimer before users can actually see the my content.

I'm using this template for the modal:

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

            <h2>Modal Box</h2>

        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

I have also created the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raving/1mhsynmw/)

Now I want to autoopen the modal on pageload. Unfortunately I only can find solutions using jQuery. Is there a way without JavaScript?

Kind regards,
Alex.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with purely HTML and CSS. Any reason you're avoiding jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work for you without using JavaScript.

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> <a href="#openModal" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

    <h2>Modal Box</h2>

    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```